# Should offset().top ever change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to jQuery and am trying to do something with scrolling. Through my research I've come across scrollTop() and offset() as tools to use for this. I was running a test where pushing a button would alert the value of offset().top of a div. When I scroll a little bit and press the button, that value changes. I was under the impression that this value should remain the same since it's the distance from the div to the top of the document doesn't change when I scroll. Could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide example of your test using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You're probably moving something, either the document or the element, as scrolling by itself should not alter the offset.

Comment: Are you scrolling the entire page or a div?

Comment: *"...example of your test using jsfiddle..."* Or http://jsbin.com, and **always** put the code and markup in the question as well.

Comment: I'm scrolling just the div

Answer (score 2):

If the element you're measuring is in a scrollable container, then yes, `top` can change, because the scrolling of the container is considered. `top` will be the visual distance from the top of the document to the element. If the element has a container that's scrolled, and you change that scrolling, that distance changes.

Consider:

```
<div style="height: 300px; overflow: scroll">
  <p>x</p>
  <!-- lots and lots more of those -->
  <p id="target">click me</p>
</div>
```

If you scroll the containing `div`, the visual distance from the top of the document to the top of `#target` changes.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ejomur/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ejomur/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

`Element.offset().top;` is the amount of pixels from the top of the document the element is, so if you do this

```
alert( $('#element').offset().top );

$('#element').css('margin-top', '50px');

alert( $('#element').offset().top );
```

You should see a change in values

Whereas `scrollTop();` is for scrollable elements so it will detect how far down the scroller is 
This will only work with the `html` or `body` unless your element has `overflow:scroll`

so

```
alert( $('#element').scrollTop() );
// Scroll the Element within 5 seconds

window.setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert( $('#element').scrollTop() );
}, 5000);
```

**Cut a long story short and you could say**

`offset` with change when the element is moved and `scrollTop` will change when the element is scrolled